# How can I populate my TableView with multidimensional json

Tags: ios, swift

I need to populate my TableView, and customize the cells to something like:

> Click in the Cell Services to open two nivels, Social Service and Other Service, when I click in one they automatically call's the number.

I have this json response:

```
var phones = {
   "services": [
            {
                  "id": "1",
                  "nome": "Social Service",
                  "numero": "9999-6666"
            },
            {
                  "id": "2",
                  "nome": "Other Service",
                  "numero": "9999-7777"
            }
   ],
   "directorship": [
            {
                  "id": "3",
                  "nome": "Directorship 1",
                  "numero": "9999-8888"
            },
            {
                  "id": "4",
                  "nome": "Directorship 2",
                  "numero": "9999-9999"
            }
   ]
};
```

I'm using Alamofire+SwiftJson, in non dimensional json works fine, I guess that i need to change my for but i dont know how:

Example of my request:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
  var texto: [String] = []@ IBOutlet weak
  var table: UITableView!

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
      self.table.reloadData()
    }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    table.delegate = self
    table.dataSource = self

    loadPosts()
  }

  func loadPosts() {
    let url = "http://puc.vc/painel/webservice/telefones/"
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url)
      .responseJSON {
        response in

          if
        let value: AnyObject = response.result.value {
          let post = JSON(value)
          for (_, subJson) in post {
            self.texto.append(subJson.stringValue)
          }
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
          self.table!.reloadData()
        })
      }
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) - > Int {
    return self.texto.count
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) - > UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel ? .text = self.texto[indexPath.row]
    print(self.texto[indexPath.row])
    return cell
  }

}
```

I need something like that:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you need two tableViews or UICollectionView? (or sections)

Comment: @MANIAK_dobrii I dont have idea which method is better, when I search about tableview I see that most commom use is populate texts and UICollectionView  pictures, can you demonstrate one example to solve this problem ?

Comment: as @MANIAK_dobrii said, u need 2 section, u can split that json into 2 array

Comment: I'm not sure what do you want to achieve. Picture (or pseudographics) would be sufficient.

Comment: @MANIAK_dobrii Just populate text have no image there

Comment: @Highlander I mean here, on stackoverflow. It's hard to see what are you asking, I have several different guesses. It could help if you draw a picture where you describe what you want schematically and attach it to your question.

Comment: @MANIAK_dobrii Better ?

Comment: what about creating a custom `UITableViewCell` which would have a header and two grey strips for the numbers; via custom protocol and delegate classes you could handle the tap on the phone numbers explicitly.

Comment: @holex You have some example or documentation site to learn that ?

Comment: @Highlander, I'm sure you will find hundreds of tutorials of making custom table cell views around the web; I would link the [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html) about that, but I'm sure you will be able to find much more advanced solutions some unofficial developer sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking on your image, you want UITableView sections. I'll provide some naive example, it is prone to errors, but that's just a hint, so I expect you to enhance it.

`phones` is a dictionary with two keys "services" and "directorship", we'll use this fact and expect it to always to be true, behind those keys are arrays of dictionaries with three key value pairs each. For the sake of simplicity, we're going to have two arrays of dictionaries, one for services, one for directorship. At first we need to extract them:

```
let post = JSON(value)
let services = post["services"] // put it into self.services
let directorship = post["directorship"] // put it into self.directorship
```

note, that in the real world they could be missing or of invalid type (i.e. say, string instead of array), I don't take that into account.

Then we use those arrays like this:

```
// We tell that we have two sections in our table view (services+directorship)
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView)
    -> Int {
    return 2 
}

// Then we return appropriate number of rows for each sections
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)
    -> Int {
    if section == 0
    {
        return self.services.count
    }
    else
    {
        return self.directorship.count
    }
}

// Configure cells appropriately
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) - > UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    if section == 0
    {
        cell.textLabel ? .text = self.services[indexPath.row]["nome"]
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel ? .text = self.directorship[indexPath.row]["nome"]
    }
    return cell
}

// return appropriate section header title
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    titleForHeaderInSection section: Int)
    -> String {
    if section == 0
    {
        return "Services"
    }
    else
    {
        return "Directorship"
    }
}
```

Note please, that I expect you not just copy paste that code (it could not work, I'm more objc yet and writing this in a browser), but read it and analyze.

In a real world it's better to create model (i.e. class like "Service" with phone, name and id) for your table view, extract web related logic somewhere else, use that web logic to obtain "json", convert it to your model (again in some separate class like "MySuperModel") and feed that model into your tableView. Fast search gave me this: http://www.pumpmybicep.com/2014/07/04/uitableview-sectioning-and-indexing/, but I think you might find much more info on the web.